# Jquery ui slider: value, min and max in the html

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, uislider

I am making some sliders with jquery-ui and i have a question how i can do the follow:

I have this html code:

```
<div class="slider range-slide">
    <b>A range slider:</b>
    <span class="amount"></span>
    <div class="slide"></div> 
</div>
```

And this is the js:

```
$(".range-slide").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $(".slide", $this).slider({
        values: [30, 60],
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        range: true,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("span.amount", $this).html("" + ui.values[0] + 
                                         " - " + ui.values[1]);
        }
    });
    $(".range-slide span.amount").html("" + $(".slide").slider("values", 0) + 
                                       " - " + $(".slide").slider("values", 1));
});
```

Everyting is working fine but how can i do someting like this:

```
<div class="slider range-slide">
    <b>A range slider:</b>
    <span class="amount"></span>
    <div class="slide" value="30,60" max="100" min="10"></div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your slider to use those values.

```
$(".slide", $this).slider({
    values: [30, 60],
    min: $(this).attr('min'),
    max: $(this).attr('max'),
    range: true,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("span.amount", $this).html("" + ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
    }
});
```

**UPDATED:**
Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zYChY/1/)

```
$(".range-slide div.slide").each(function() {
$(this).slider({
    values: [30, 60],
    min: parseInt($(this).attr('min')),
    max:  parseInt($(this).attr('max')),
    range: true,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("span.amount", $(this).parent()).html("" + ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
    }
});
$(".range-slide span.amount").html("" + $(this).slider("values", 0) + " - " + $(this).slider("values", 1));
});
```

**UPDATE 2**
Use split to separate the values by commas and assign them to variables. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zYChY/3/)

```
$(".range-slide div.slide").each(function() {
    values = $(this).attr('value').split(',');
   firstVal = values[0];
    secondVal = values[1];


    $(this).slider({
        values: [firstVal , secondVal],
        min: parseInt($(this).attr('min')),
        max:  parseInt($(this).attr('max')),
        range: true,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("span.amount", $(this).parent()).html("" + ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
        }
    });
    $(".range-slide span.amount").html("" + $(this).slider("values", 0) + " - " + $(this).slider("values", 1));
    });
```

Comment: Sorry mate, this is not working :-(... and the value i want to set that to in the HTML.

Comment: Hi Amin Eshaq, this is working but how about the values how can i do that one?

Comment: Hi Amin, it is working great but the values... how can i set them? (values: [30, 60]) that one i want in the HTML to :), thnx for the help!

Comment: Does work. I have checked out the fiddle and tested myself with splitting values. I think, the first version lead into trouble with the references to $(this).

Comment: Amin Eshaq check this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZwG9Q/ in the beginning the values are the same but in the HTML they arent... how is this possible?

Comment: give the selection of amount a context of this's parent.. $(".range-slide span.amount", $(this).parent())

Comment: check out this http://jsfiddle.net/ZwG9Q/2/ declare rangeSpan = $(this).siblings('span.amount'); at the top and use that to modify the amount

Comment: Almost Amin haha... now when you move the slider at the top the amount of the slider at the bottom will change and not his own...

Comment: haha comeon man... i feel like you're programmer for hire..Check this out.. http://jsfiddle.net/ZwG9Q/3/

Comment: Amin i am not a real JS programmer i am more a designer, HTML and CSS guy... but i am learning :-) this is working great, thnx!

Answer (score 0):

untested ...

```
$(".range-slide").each(function() {
var $this = $(this);
$(".slide", $this).slider({
    values: $(this).attr('value').split(','),
    min: $(this).attr('min'),
    max: $(this).attr('max'),
    range: true,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("span.amount", $this).html("" + ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
    }
});
$(".range-slide span.amount").html("" + $(".slide").slider("values", 0) + " - " + $(".slide").slider("values", 1));
});
```

Comment: Same for you HBublitz... this is not working and i getting an error by you Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined